# Print people of certain age from file

Tags: java, nio

I'm writing a program which reads a txt file containing inforamtion about people ( in this order: [surname] [name] [year of birth] [sex]), and then prints the people of certain age ( woman 60 or above and men 65 or above).
the txt file looks like this:

```
Stewart John 1940 m
Mary Jane 1940 k
```

And here is the program:

```
public class Main3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> outList = new ArrayList<>();

        final int year = 2018;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Path path = Paths.get("zadanie3.txt");
        try {
            for (String line : Files.readAllLines(path)) {
                String[] tab = line.split(" ");
                if (tab[3].equals("m")) {
                    if (year - (Integer.parseInt(tab[2])) >= 65) {
                        outList.add(line);


                    }
                     if (tab[3].equals("k")) {
                        if (year - (Integer.parseInt(tab[2]) ) >= 60) {
                            outList.add(line);


                        }


                    }


                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.out.println(outList);
    }
}
```

It should print information about both of the people from txt file (since they are both of the age that I'm looking for) but it only pritns the first one. From what I've seen in debbuger for some reason the program only checks the first i statement and  quits without checking the second. Do you have any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have nested your `if` statements by accident.

Try this:

```
public class Main3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> outList = new ArrayList<>();

        final int year = 2018;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Path path = Paths.get("zadanie3.txt");
        try {
            for (String line : Files.readAllLines(path)) {
                String[] tab = line.split(" ");
                if (tab[3].equals("m")) {
                    if (year - (Integer.parseInt(tab[2])) >= 65) {
                        outList.add(line);

                    }

                } else if (tab[3].equals("k")) {
                    if (year - (Integer.parseInt(tab[2]) ) >= 60) {
                        outList.add(line);

                    }

                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.out.println(outList);
    }
}
```

So your code was actually checking if the sex was `"k"` after it had already established that it was  `"m"`.

Comment: Will do as soon as i can

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I forgot about the time minimum.